# How chromecast sender works on devices without Google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast

In our application chromecast button unavailable on devices without google play services (like kindle fire) and ask for update google play services if it outdated.
But I see chromecast in Red Bull TV https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nousguide.android.rbtv
works on devices wirh outdeted google play services without asking anything and even on kindle fire.

How it possible?

Comment: `MediaRouteActionProvider`, `MediaRouteButton`, and `RemotePlaybackClient` are part of the Android SDK without the Cast SDK -- perhaps that is what they are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red Bull TV was first built using the Google Cast Preview SDK (as part of the [New Chromecast apps for the holiday release](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2013/12/new-chromecast-apps-for-holidays.html)) that did not rely on Google Play Services and hence could work on devices with outdated or without any Google Play Services. However, the official Google Cast SDK (released on February 3rd, 2014) does require a recent version of Google Play Services and all Preview SDK apps were disabled as of [March 17th, 2014](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/V1jPi46oPsQ) (which is probably the reason why Red Bull TV's ratings since that point are almost all 1 stars due to Chromecast crashing/failing).

Comment: So you mean this is impossible using public SDK?

Comment: That's correct. Currently the public SDK is limited to Google Play Service enabled Android devices, iOS, and Google Chrome.